# Filtering a .CSV file based on consecutive numbers in a line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a CSV file as follows:

```
                 1st       2nd      3rd       4th
   ID      ...   Res       Res      Res       Res        (other columns) ...

RZ_AUTO_1, 1cx0, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_2, 1drz, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_3, 1ffk, C208, 0, G209, 0, A665, 0, A666, 0, CG/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_4, 1ffk, C2767, 0, C2682, 0, G2679, 0, A2681, 0, CC/GA Naked ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_5, 1ffk, G2574, 0, C2575, 0, G2798, 0, A2776, 0, GC/GA Single ribose-zipper
```

What I would like to do is extract rows where (the number of First_Residue (the third field) & Second_Residue ($5) are consecutive) AND (the number of Third_Residue ($7) & Fourth_Residue ($9) are consecutive). Example of output would be like this:

```
RZ_AUTO_1, 1cx0, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_2, 1drz, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_3, 1ffk, C208, 0, G209, 0, A665, 0, A666, 0, CG/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
```

Lines 4 & 5 will be removed as the residue numbers are not consecutive.

How can I do this using awk or sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of the fields to be compared has a single non-numeric prefix character (`C` or `A` in your example), then you should be able to extract and compare the numeric substrings directly in awk e.g.

```
$ awk -F"[ \t,]+" 'substr($5,2)+0==substr($3,2)+1 && substr($9,2)+0==substr($7,2)+1' file.csv
RZ_AUTO_1, 1cx0, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper 
RZ_AUTO_2, 1drz, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper 
RZ_AUTO_3, 1ffk, C208, 0, G209, 0, A665, 0, A666, 0, CG/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -F, -anle '
    map { s/\D//g } @F;
    print if ++$F[2] == $F[4] and ++$F[6] == $F[8];
' file
RZ_AUTO_1, 1cx0, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_2, 1drz, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_3, 1ffk, C208, 0, G209, 0, A665, 0, A666, 0, CG/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
```

Answer (score 0):

This Bash script does what you want but not using just `sed` and `awk`. I'm sure if more time was spent in developing this it could be further refined, but it, roughly, does what you want.

```
$ more cmd.bash 
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do 
    f1=$(echo "$line" | awk -F", " '{print $3}')
    f2=$(echo "$line" | awk -F", " '{print $7}')
    echo "$line" | grep  "${f1}.*$(expr ${f1:2} + 1).*${f2}.*$(expr ${f2:2} + 1)"
done <file
```

#### Example run

```
$ ./cmd.bash 
RZ_AUTO_1, 1cx0, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_2, 1drz, C118, B, C119, B, A165, B, A166, B, CC/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
RZ_AUTO_3, 1ffk, C208, 0, G209, 0, A665, 0, A666, 0, CG/AA Canonical ribose-zipper
```

#### Weaknesses

One area where it needs to be further enhanced is in the selection of the matches in the `grep` line. This can lead to false positives in it's current form. This can be done better using a tool such a `awk` or by enhancing the pattern which `grep` is using to match the lines.